# How do I construct a 3D bivariate normal density surface in SAS?

Tags: sas, statistics

So I've managed to define a grid over the definition region (arbitrary for now) of the density function in PROC IML. But, being a newbie in SAS, I have no clue on how to draw the surface. The problem isn't so much the syntax as it's coming up with an idea that doesn't transcend the functionality that SAS is able to achieve, which, based off of the info. I have gathered so far, seems limited.

Comment: Do you have SAS/Graph licensed?  Here is link to sample of PROC G3D outputs. https://support.sas.com/sassamples/graphgallery/PROC_G3D.html

Comment: I suppose it's included in the licensed download link my university provided. Thanks for the suggestion!